# Merge multiple databases in couchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have multiple databases wherein each database is harvesting some hundred thousand tweets. I am not looking to merge these databases together to get more in depth analysis. However, I cannot find anything which could help me merging these databases, which were created in `CouchDB`.

```
$ npm install -g couchdb-merge
```

Installed this, and then ran below:

```
$ couchdb-merge --database aus_vs_pak_new.couch nz_vs_wi_new.couch --database merge.couch
```

However, I get error :

```
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/local/bin/couchdb-merge: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
....
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to merge two different databases into one. You can do this from couchdb itself by using the [_replicate](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/common.html#post--_replicate) endpoint.

If you have access to futon then you can click on the replicator link in the sidebar to replicate with the help of a user interface.

After merging the databases aus_vs_pak and nz_vs_wi into a new database say "crikcet_analysis" the final database will contain everything from the two sources. Keep in mind though the indexes are not replicated and you will have to recreate them.